# javascript vs mysql weekday : different first day of the week

Tags: javascript, mysql

I noticed that javascript has this index:

```
[0] Sunday
[1] Monday
.....
```

while (my)sql has this index:

```
[0] Monday
[1] Tuesday
.....
```

Two questions:

1) Which should I follow, meaning for locale purposes which one is the most used?

2) Is there a way to sync them, or I have to consider this discrepancy every time I write my code? (it's a little bit annoying and it can generate mistakes...) What are the possible solutions?

Thanks!!

Comment: Which day is the start of the week is an administrative decision. Javascript copied much (all?) of its Date behaviour from Java which might explain why Sunday is 0. These issues pervade any kind of calendaring application, try ISO 8601 (Monday) first and make sure your solution can accommodate either as a **preference**, not based on region (or "locale").

Comment: PS. You might find [*this discussion on stackexchange*](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/170496/why-did-the-iso-8601-committee-choose-monday-as-the-first-day-of-the-week) interesting.

Comment: Thanks Rob! So I guess that the answer is that I MUST pay attention to this difference every time I write my code!!! I hope I will not make mistakes! I will try to go with DAYOFWEEK() in MySQL that goes from 1 to 7, with 1 being Monday... Do you know about an analog function in javascript?